# Bootstrap 3 - Expanding an Collapsing Nested Table Rows

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web page that uses Bootstrap 3. In this page, I'm trying to show the relationship between grandparent, parent, and child. To do this, I have table rows that can expand/collapse. I've setup a Bootply [here](http://www.bootply.com/rWyiyCvU4Z). My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="grandparent" class="list-group-item">
    <div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#grandparentContent" data-role="expander" data-group-id="grandparent">
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li id="grandparentIcon">&gt;</li>
            <li>Grandparent</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse" id="grandparentContent" aria-expanded="true">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Created On</th>
            <th>Last Modified</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr data-toggle="collapse">
            <td><div>&gt;</div></td>
            <td>Parent 1</td>
            <td>04/02/2017</td>
            <td>04/04/2017</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="collapse">
            <td></td>
            <td>Child A</td>
            <td>04/01/2017</td>
            <td>04/05/2017</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="collapse">
            <td></td>
            <td>Child B</td>
            <td>04/03/2017</td>
            <td>04/04/2017</td>
          </tr>          

          <tr data-toggle="collapse">
            <td><div>&gt;</div></td>
            <td>Parent 2</td>
            <td>04/03/2017</td>
            <td>04/10/2017</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="collapse">
            <td></td>
            <td>Child X</td>
            <td>04/10/2017</td>
            <td>04/11/2017</td>
          </tr>          
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

When either a grandparent or parent is expanded, I'm trying to change the related icon from ">" to "v". However, this doesn't work. I don't understand why. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like show.bs.collapse event and hidden.bs.collapse are never fired. Are you these a real events fired by bootstrap?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do what you are trying to do by adding two things:

1. A `collapsed` class that toggles each time a grandparent or parent are clicked, to represent if it is expanded or collapsed.
2. Add CSS so that when the `collapsed` class is active it shows ">" and when it is not active (it is expanded) it shows a "v".

[Updated Bootply Here](http://www.bootply.com/oxKYaxmDYF)

Your main issue is that you were missing `data-target` for your parent rows, and you also were only changing the grandparent icon with your jQuery.

Key jQuery

```
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('collapsed');
});
```

Key CSS

```
.collapsed .icon-class:before {
    content: '>';
}
.icon-class:before {
    content: 'v';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a fixed version, change the code to your own liking.

http://www.bootply.com/sCCEzKCLsI#

But essentially the 
`show.bs.collapse` and `hide.bs.collapse` events are fired from the `.collapse` and not the the `data-toggle="collapse"` element.

Comment: Why don't "Parent 1" and "Parent 2" expand / collapse in your example though?

Answer (score 0):

Also to addition to [WilomGfx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43350043/3649914), you need to assign the `data-target` to the table rows.

Preview [here](http://www.bootply.com/bonkCjnG0F)

HTML

```
<div id="grandparent" class="list-group-item">
    <div id="expander" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#grandparentContent" data-role="expander" data-group-id="grandparent">
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li id="grandparentIcon">&gt;</li>
            <li>Grandparent</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse" id="grandparentContent" aria-expanded="true">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Created On</th>
            <th>Last Modified</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#childOne">
            <td><div>&gt;</div></td>
            <td>Parent 1</td>
            <td>04/02/2017</td>
            <td>04/04/2017</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="collapse" id="childOne">
            <td></td>
            <td>Child A</td>
            <td>04/01/2017</td>
            <td>04/05/2017</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="collapse">
            <td></td>
            <td>Child B</td>
            <td>04/03/2017</td>
            <td>04/04/2017</td>
          </tr>          

          <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#childTwo">
            <td><div>&gt;</div></td>
            <td>Parent 2</td>
            <td>04/03/2017</td>
            <td>04/10/2017</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="collapse" id="childTwo">
            <td></td>
            <td>Child X</td>
            <td>04/10/2017</td>
            <td>04/11/2017</td>
          </tr>          
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  var groupId = $('#expander').attr('data-group-id');
  console.log(groupId);
  if (groupId) {
    $('#grandparentIcon').html('v');
  }
});

$('.collapse').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
  var groupId = $('#expander').attr('data-group-id');
  console.log(groupId);
  if (groupId) {
    $('#' + groupId + 'Icon').html('>');
  }
});
```